# обратиться к статической переменной класса в функции

Tags: c++

есть класс

```
class Progress {
  public:
    static int border;
    static void set ( const int border ) {
      base::border = border;
    }
};
```

как мне обратиться к переменной border статического класса, чтобы присвоить ей значение?

Comment: `Progress::border` Но вы  уж определитесь - "к переменной border статического класса" или "к статической переменной класса"...

Comment: Или просто `border`, если переименовать параметр.